# MultiDexApplication not recognized

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

Trying to use MultiDexApplication in my app, but the class is not recognized when I try to extend my application activity with it.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myapp'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 115
        versionName '4.8'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            runProguard true
            zipAlign true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'

    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

You can see that I'm compiling on 21, using the latest build tools, and the latest google play services and support library.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: I haven't. Been trying for a couple days now. Have you made any breakthroughs yet?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

MultiDexApplication class is not part of appcompat-v7 library. It is being shipped in a separate jar (called android-support-multidex).

Find the **android-support-multidex.jar** under **/sdk/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs** (available from revision 21 of support library) and copy it to your project's **libs** folder.

**Update (11/5/2014)**:
The jar is now available in central repository:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

For more info, see [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

**Update (27/9/2021)**:
Jetpack (AndroidX) users should add this as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Please instead reference the multidex library via maven/gradle:  dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
} // Note, the library version number may be greater by the time you read this.

Comment: Updated library version :  'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

Comment: please use , implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

Answer (score 26):

Although this question is quite old, I got this error in a multi-module setup when trying to build the different modules together as one APK for API < 21. I already refactored to AndroidX, but the multidex docs don't mention AndroidX yet.

If you are using AndroidX, make sure to replace the old multidex dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

with the new one

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
```

Comment: add this line to Manifest android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Comment: @IvanVovk How MultiDex is installed is completely up to the developer - be it through `MultiDex#install` or through registering `MultiDexApplication` in the Manifest. This is only relevant for including the MultiDex dependency in the first place.

Comment: Jesus Christ Google, why don't you update your Documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex ??

Answer (score 2):

I have followed [THIS](http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/multi-dex-to-rescue-from-infamous-65536.html) blog post according to which MultiDexApplication should be included in r21 of support library.

My IDE had trouble resolving it also.

I made it work for now with the help of [MULTIDEX](https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex) github project by adding (you can see more details on the project's page):

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex

        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
    }
}
```

and adding $project_dir/multidex.keep file with following contents:

```
android/support/multidex/BuildConfig.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V19.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V4.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor$1.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor.class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil$CentralDirectory.class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil.class
```

The github project page mentions also some consideration for the contents of your implementation of MultiDexApplication class:

> - The static fields in your application class will be loaded before the
>     MultiDex#installbe called! So the suggestion is to avoid static fields
>     with types that can be placed out of main classes.dex file.
> - The methods of your application class may not have access to other classes
>     that are loaded after your application class. As workarround for this,
>     you can create another class (any class, in the example above, I use
>     Runnable) and execute the method content inside it.

Comment: What does the `--multi-dex` additionalParameter do?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think it is what is enabling multi dex. By now multidex should work without this workaround. Please see Alex's updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586969/724146

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution :)

Upgrade to jdk 8 and change JDK location in Android Studio in

File > Project Structure > SDK Location

Find and change JDK location and click OK

Comment: This is not relevant to JDK