# Android App Crashes on Real Device If apk is manually installed

Tags: java, android, crash

My Application is running fine in Emulators and even in real devices installed by android studio for debugging purpose, but it is crashing if installed manually using apk file.

I am ready to paste any other codes, like Activity if required.

Here is the logcat:

```
04-14 12:20:44.392 6220-6220/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-14 12:20:44.465 6220-6220/test.planner W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/test.planner-1/lib/arm
04-14 12:20:44.467 6220-6220/test.planner I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-14 12:20:44.470 6220-6220/test.planner D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-14 12:20:44.471 6220-6220/test.planner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.planner, PID: 6220
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{test.planner/test.planner.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.planner.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/test.planner-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/test.planner-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.planner.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/test.planner-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/test.planner-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.planner.MainActivity
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: pls disable the instant run feature in settings, if it is enable.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557737/multidexapplication-not-recognized

Comment: @DixitPatel Working now! :) thanks mate.

Comment: You may find your answer in this article [NoClassDefError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: I couldnt find instant run iin android studio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Just go to:**

```
Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy --> Instant run.
```

and disable `instant run`.

Comment: Can not see instant run in android studio 3.5.2

Comment: I couldn't find this option in Android studio 2020.3.1.

Answer (score 5):

If you just upgraded your android studio.

You will not have this option to `disable -> Instant Run`. (not on the menu)

Seems like with new android studio and gradle upgrade in order to install an apk you need to properly build it.

**Option 1:** with gradle from command line

```
./gradlew :appName:clean  
./gradlew :appName:build
```

**Option 2:** from android studio

`Android Studio -> build -> build APK` (or generate sighed APK)

The generated apk can be installed fine on a device.

**Note:** if you start a new applicate with this version of android studio you will see that when you run from studio there is no apk generated anymore.

Comment: Thank you!!! I've been banging my head for several days because of this!
I knew about the problem with the "Instant Run" option and have been working without it for some time now!  But it never crossed my mind that "properly building the apk" with option 2 would help!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem.

Note the size of Apk, it would be very small in size , this is because of the instant run feature in enabled. Just disable it

May be Android Studio is not including all files in Apk, when we use the instant run to fasten the process.

Any body know why this happening?

Go to :

```
Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy --> Instant run.
```

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy --> Instant run.
and disable instant run.