# Android app crashes if Installing manually and works fine if installs with android studio

Tags: android

> Process: com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff, PID: 5995
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff.MyApp:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff.MyApp" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff-7Od1mP0FDm8Z4b5SncuoVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff-7Od1mP0FDm8Z4b5SncuoVg==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:971)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5765)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff.MyApp" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff-7Od1mP0FDm8Z4b5SncuoVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.webdealersolutions.abdullahriaz.localstuff-7Od1mP0FDm8Z4b5SncuoVg==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1086)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:965)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Multidexing enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App Crashes on Real Device If apk is manually installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406398/android-app-crashes-on-real-device-if-apk-is-manually-installed)

Comment: Did you enable minify?

Comment: but it is not showing debugger in my android studio

Comment: Disable instant run from settings and make a build

Comment: I did minifyEnabled false

Comment: Disable instant run and check again

Answer (score 0):

Your app crash by installing manually because you have enabled

> instant run

and not related to [multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588459/what-is-android-multidex) just disable instant run and install app on your phone

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825543/didnt-find-class-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider/45548131#45548131)