# FragmentTransaction.replace() crashes - but only in release build

Tags: java, android

when I execute the following code in debug (ADB via USB) it works, but when I install a generated release .apk, it crashes. More precisely the following code crashes.

```java
.replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
```

Here is the full version of the code.

```java
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
}
```

I found the error from the Google Play which says it throws an `IllegalStateExcetion`. I do not know any other way of retrieving error messages since it works perfectly fine in debug mode.

This is the corresponding XML file:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the message displayed in LogCat.

Comment: Use Fabric Crashlytics (Now Firebase Crashlytics) or some other crashlytics api to get ccrash reports in release version.

Comment: Please disable the instant run and then try again. And yes, if that does not work, please post your `proguard-rules.pro` file.

Comment: @ReazMurshed instant run is disabled, and now I get a exception. My proguard-rules.pro file is all commented-out.

Comment: Please don't use `android-studio` tag if your question does not specifically deal with IDE itself

Answer (score 0):

I believe disabling **Instant run** may resolve this. Take a look at this thread:

[Android App Crashes on Real Device If apk is manually installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406398/android-app-crashes-on-real-device-if-apk-is-manually-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Had to make SettingsFragment public, now it looks like it works.