# Cannot enable facebook login with MultiDex

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-login

This whole thing should be easy but I still cannot get it right

I added the Facebook login implementation to my app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
```

I made sure that the following is implemented in my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

When I synch and run I receive the following error:

```
Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 71724 > 65536)
```

There is an explanation how to solve it here by installing MultiDex: [MultiDexApplication not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557737/multidexapplication-not-recognized)

Since I'm using AndroidX, I added in my app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
```

In my manifest file:

```
<application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
...
```

And of course added:

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
```

Now when I run the app, it crashes immediately without giving any error message. When I remove the facebook login implementation, it works fine, so I assume that MultiDex is working properly? What can I do to figure out why my app crashes with facebook login?

I also enabled those in my gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create your custom myApplication class that extends MultiDexApplication. and add this class in Android Manifest.xml file

 *Android Manifest.xml

<application
        android:name=".myApplication"

 add after that update your myApplication.java class.
          public class myApplication extends MultiDexApplication {



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }



}
```

Comment: Hello Mayur, in what activity should I implement the myApplication class? Thanks for your help

Comment: You dont have to implement,just mention that class in  AndroidManifest.xml file                                                            <application
        android:name=".myApplication"
 android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the exact same crash

Comment: Can you please post what error is it's showing ..? @sir-haver

Comment: that's the thing, it crashes immediately without displaying any error

Answer (score 0):

you should use custom Application, like:

- App

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

- AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".application.App"
```

Comment: Is "App" my luncher activity? such as MainActivity? And the application name in AndroidManifest should literally be ".application.App" ? Thanks

Comment: ```
<application
        android:name=".App"
```
AndroidManifest.xml  File  have <application  />  label

".App" is path

Comment: It's still crashing

Comment: e..it's ok. 
you should find other solutions

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the whole problem was caused by Facebook login wasn't the latest version, although the version I used was copied straight from their official docs.

Version I'm using that solved the problem:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.13.0'
```